# Как добавить условие в конструкцию if

Tags: python

```
elif z == "buy shovel":
        money = money - s1
        L = L + 5
        s1 = shops(k)
        print(f"balance: {money}")
```

z - это ввод

money - баланс

s1 - цена предмета

shops(k) - функция, которая
увеличивает цену предмета

L - +сила за предмет

Вопрос:

Как сделать, чтобы нельзя было купить товар когда `money` меньше `s1` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ну дополните свое условие вторым

```
elif z == "buy shovel" and money >= s1:
```